# How to append the repeated values to same key in dictionary list

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I have below dictionary list which contains repeated values. i need to append the repeated values to same key and remain should store as it in the dictionary list.

```
veh_entry=[{'name': 'scott', 'id': '17'},{'name': 'thomas', 'id': '18'}, {'name': 'tony', 'id': '17'}]
```

i tried with below approach, but not seems to be working as expected

```
add=[]
test={}
for item in veh_entry:
   if item['id'] not in add:
        test['name']=item['name']
        add.append(item['id'])
    else:
        test['name']=(test['name']+ ','+item['name'])
```

#expected:
the expected dictionary must be as follows:

```
[{'name': 'scott, tony', 'id':'17'},{'name': 'thomas', 'id': '18'}]
```

Comment: "not seems to be working as expected" Then what *is* it doing? A [MCVE] means providing the observed output too.

Answer (score 0):

So the basic logic was to compare the ids of different item in the list and if the id's match then join the name and remove the repeated item from the list

```
final_result = []
for i in range(len(veh_entry)-1):
    for j in range(i+1,len(veh_entry)):
        a = dict()
        if veh_entry[i]['id'] == veh_entry[j]['id']:
            a['name'] = veh_entry[i]['name'] +','+veh_entry[j]['name']
            a['id'] = veh_entry[i]['id']
            veh_entry.pop(j)
            final_result.append(a)
        else:
            final_result.append(veh_entry[j])
        

print(final_result)
```

Output:- [{'name': 'thomas', 'id': '18'}, {'name': 'scott,tony', 'id': '17'}]

Answer (score 0):

You can go with this:

```
def remove_dup(arr):
names=[] # using list here
ids=[] # instead of dict
for x in arr:
    id,name=x['id'],x['name']
    if id not in ids: # search for existing id
        ids.append(id)
        names.append(name)
    else:
        names[ids.index(id)]+=", "+name
        
return [{'name':name,'id':id} for name,id in zip(names,ids)]

veh_entry=[{'name': 'scott', 'id': '17'},{'name': 'thomas', 'id': '18'}, {'name': 'tony', 'id': '17'}]

print(remove_dup(veh_entry))
```